# Is Magento 2 Official Documentation easy to understand for newbie?

Tags: discussion, magento2, documentation

When i started learning magento 2, I went through the official documentation. But it was so complex and deep that i didn't grasp the concepts well, so i decided to look for easy to understand tutorials.

**Do you find it complex too? (Please answer).**

**Do you think a newbie can understand it well? (Please answer).**

I think if the documentation is written well,it will make developer life hell lot easy.

**Do you think the documentation needed to change??**

Comment: This question should not be asked here, Magento meta site is for discussing the workings and policies of Magento Stack Exchange . Magento Learning or Issues  should not be discussed here.

Answer (score 6):

> Do you find it complex too?

No, I think the documentation is very clear, but you should not read it from the beginning to the end at one time, just use it as a handbook.

> Do you think a newbie can understand it well?

Yes. In case you are interested in "How the plugins work?" you can find the answer in the documentation and you can understand it. Documentation is clear by the specific questions, but it hides a wide information which you should learn manually by debugging the Magento 2 code-base.

> Do you think the documentation needed to change?

Yes, it should grow :)

I recommend you to search some thematic blog-posts on the web, which can make some aspects of the Magento 2 more clear (when you write a code all things looks hard, but when it completely works it looks so easy).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer, really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it should grow